# GetModuleFileName not returning Path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, getmodulefilename

I'm trying to get the current directory under win7 with VS c++ but

```cpp
TCHAR pBuf[MAX_PATH];
int bytes = GetModuleFileName(NULL, pBuf, MAX_PATH);
std::cout << bytes << "   " << pBuf << "   " <<   GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

returns length 58 and what I believe to be a pointer in pBuf pointing to 68. Errorcode is 0.

Thank you!

Comment: If this is Unicode build, use `wcout` instead of `cout`.

Comment: If you want the above program should run then the change the character set in VS to multibyte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [<< operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba4ae8wb.aspx) does not accept `const TCHAR*` as a string argument, and you have it printed out as a generic pointer.

One of the ways to fix the problem is to use `A` version of the API (`CHAR` buffer and `GetModuleFileNameA` function):

```
CHAR pBuf[MAX_PATH];
int bytes = GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, pBuf, MAX_PATH);
std::cout << bytes << "   " << pBuf << "   " <<   GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up converting pBuf to char* via wcstombs_s since i just wanted to open a file.